# how come ubuntu is not compatible to the galaxy note 3

Tags: ubuntu-touch

It is not compatible to the galaxy note 3 and I do not understand why it is only compatible to the galaxy nexus.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?
If Ubuntu Touch is compatible with the Samsung Galaxy Note 3
Or why the phone is not compatible with Ubuntu, and how to recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu-touch is in development. At first they will get it working and stable on just a few devices, after this more work on porting to other devices will (I assume) have more priority. It doesn't make sense to try to develop the system for everything at once.